# ALSA: proper way to playback audio - blocking mode and threads

Tags: linux, alsa

I cannot get the correct way to write my loop to play audio and/or I don't understand correctly the meaning of start_threshold, stop_threshold and avail_min parameters for Alsa. I'd like to reach the lowest latency and know the correct parameters to modify in order to make my capture-process-playback chain tolerant to variations in the audio processing time. In this example I'm reading samples from file, to focus on the playback part.

This is my output device configuration, opened in blocking mode (Ubuntu 16.04, PulseAudio present, `default` device):

```
ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : FLOAT_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 6144
  period_size  : 2048
  period_time  : 46439
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 4096
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 2048
  stop_threshold   : 2048
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 6917529027641081856
```

My playback thread gets audio buffers from another thread which reads samples from file (hence faster than the playback rate). This is the playback function (Cython code):

```
cdef int play_buffer(self, buffer_t *buf) nogil:

    cdef int rc
    cdef long t0, t1

    t0 = timestamp_us()
    rc = snd_pcm_writei(self.handle, buf.data, buf.period_size)
    t1 = timestamp_us()

    if rc >= 0:
        printf("[%ld / %6ld] snd_pcm_writei: OK %d\n", t0, t1 - t0, rc)
    else:
        printf("[%ld / %6ld] snd_pcm_writei: ERR %d [%s]\n", t0, t1 - t0, rc, snd_strerror(rc))

    if rc < 0:
        if rc == -errno.EPIPE:
            rc = snd_pcm_prepare(self.handle)
            printf("snd_pcm_prepare: %d\n", rc)

        else:
            printf("play_buffer ERR %d\n", rc)
            return WRITE_ERROR

    elif rc != buf.period_size:
        printf('snd_pcm_writei(): short write %d != %d', rc, buf.period_size)

    return OK
```

This is the output (`timestamp_us()` returns the system time in microseconds):

```
[1525102519583090 /    540] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519585406 /     16] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
[1525102519587798 /    393] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519590018 /      3] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
[1525102519592303 /    415] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519594523 /      3] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
[1525102519596823 /   1905] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519599242 /     12] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
[1525102519601707 /   8023] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519609754 /     45] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519609811 /     27] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519609847 /     28] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519611328 /     40] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519613546 /  48501] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519662079 /  50678] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519712804 /  49487] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519762318 /  50521] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519812868 /  49497] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519862394 /  49630] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519912051 /  49875] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102519961953 /  50647] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102520012655 /  49949] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102520062632 /  49713] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102520112373 /  49495] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102520161898 /     62] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102520161977 /  50485] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
[1525102520212490 /  49514] snd_pcm_writei: OK 2048
.. continues with no errors ...
```

I don't get the reason of these EPIPE errors at the beginning; What I'm expecting is that `snd_pcm_writei` either returns immediately or waits (more or less) a period duration time before returning, because I'm in blocking mode and I'm faster to provide samples than the playback sample rate requires.
When the error sequence ends the playback is fine. Moreover, if I set the realtime priority to my threads (`pthread_setschedparam()`) I get an endless list of OK 2048 / ERR -32 and I hear only noise. This is really weird to me.

Where's my mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, the buffer is empty, so you should fill it as fast as possible, without waiting.

To reduce latency, decrease the buffer size.
To reduce the risk of underruns, increase the buffer size.
You cannot do both at the same time.  You have to choose a buffer size that balances these two goals for your particular case.

The start threshold specifies that the device automatically starts playing when that many frames are in the buffer. You should set this to the buffer size.

The stop threshold specifies that the device stops when the number of available (free) frames reaches this value. You should leave it at its default value, the buffer size.

The avail_min parameter specifies how many frames must be available before an interrupt results in you application actually being waken up.

Comment: I understand this. But my second snd_pcm_writei() comes 2.5ms after the (successful) first, compared to a period time of 46ms. I think it's fast enough. Why does it get an error?

Comment: Because you have set the stop threshold way too low.

Comment: Ok. I begin to understand. Thanks. But how can I make snd_pcm_writei() block if I'm pushing too much data or wait until I can be sure the next snd_pcm_writei() will succeed? And what's the difference between start_threshold and avail_min parameters?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

### Turns out the culprit is PulseAudio. Putting it aside through `pasuspender` everything works as I expect.

I made a step forward. I'm able to get a more stable sound output setting `buffer_size`, `start_threshold`, `stop_threshold` to 3 times the period size and `avail_min` as the period size. I still don't get the difference between avail_min and start_threshold, but this works a lot better, even with a small period size as here below:

```
ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : FLOAT_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 192
  period_size  : 64
  period_time  : 1451
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 64
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 192
  stop_threshold   : 192
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 6917529027641081856
```

I still get some EPIPE errors, usually only one at the beginning of the playback stream:

```
[1525158345182486 /     64] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158345182609 /     23] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158345182833 /    862] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158345183718 /      3] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
[1525158345184915 /     38] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158345184962 /     46] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158345185018 /   1240] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158345186281 /     33] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
```

But I still have problems with real-time sheduling. If I set the real-time scheduling to my threads sometimes I get a clean output with not EPIPE errors, but most of the time I get an endless sequence of errors and I hear only noise:

```
[1525158709952740 /     30] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709952781 /     14] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709952809 /   2163] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709954994 /      4] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
[1525158709956346 /     29] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709956385 /     15] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709956405 /   2250] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709958673 /      3] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
[1525158709959930 /     31] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709959971 /     15] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709959998 /   2334] snd_pcm_writei: OK 64
[1525158709962355 /      3] snd_pcm_writei: ERR -32 [Broken pipe]
snd_pcm_prepare: 0
```

using a bigger period size I get some more chance to obtain a clean audio stream, but still not 100% reliable.

Any hints?

Thanks.